# How to add a server in a current network? Look at the picture attach

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, switch

I would like to add a Windows server with a Web Application to the network.

From what I understand, I have to join all computers to the domain(server) and install the web application inside the root directory of the server using xampp, thus allowing every computer have access to the web application.

I currently have 30 computers, printer and internet connection.

Anyone has a better idea to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Which diagram ?

Comment: Sorry, i have added the picture again.

Comment: this one -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDkud.png

Comment: You may add a Web server anywhere in the network, no domain required. It can be referred-to by its netbios computer name - `http://server/application`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do i have to point the switch to the sever ?

Answer (score 0):

You may add a Web server anywhere in the network, no domain required.
Workgroup is entirely sufficient for a stand-alone server and a small local network.

The server can be referred-to by its NetBIOS computer name,
`http://server/application`.

You don't have to parameter anything, as
[NetBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS)
will take care of advertising the server computer, as it does for all the
other computers that you can see in Explorer when clicking Network,
if Network Discovery is enabled.

Note: If using Microsoft accounts, be aware that computers with such a login
will have problems communicating with computers using a local login.
The two types should not be mixed on one local network.
NetBIOS is also not supported on IPv6 networks, only IPv4, which is entirely
sufficient for a small network.